# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:java.io.IOException

Tags: java, react-native, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

Test fails on AWS device farm (running for iOS) after running few scripts with

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:java.io.IOException: unexpected
> end of stream on Connection{127.0.0.1:4723, proxy=DIRECT
> hostAddress=/127.0.0.1:4723 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}

Selenium-java version is 3.141.59.

When I run my script on local with platform version 12.1 and device Name is iPhone 6 plus, it runs smoothly. But fails on device farm with any device and version(I have checked on few, iPhone 7, version 11.0 is one of those).

I have tried running on many other compatible different iOS version, still face the same issue. I have tried on both 127.0.0.1:4723 and 0.0.0.0:4723.

> -[TestNG] org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{127.0.0.1:4723, proxy=DIRECT
> hostAddress=/127.0.0.1:4723 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
>
> -Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…

---

```
2019-05-24 13:48:23:165 - [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.9.1
2019-05-24 13:48:23:167 - [Appium] Non-default server args:
2019-05-24 13:48:23:170 - [Appium]   logTimestamp: true
2019-05-24 13:48:23:170 - [Appium]   defaultCapabilities: {
2019-05-24 13:48:23:170 - [Appium]     usePrebuiltWDA: true
2019-05-24 13:48:23:171 - [Appium]     derivedDataPath: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/DerivedData1JgqWF
2019-05-24 13:48:23:171 - [Appium]     platformName: iOS
2019-05-24 13:48:23:171 - [Appium]     automationName: XCUITest
2019-05-24 13:48:23:171 - [Appium]     deviceName: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:23:172 - [Appium]     app: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa
2019-05-24 13:48:23:172 - [Appium]     udid: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:23:173 - [Appium]   }
2019-05-24 13:48:23:173 - [Appium]   platformName: iOS
2019-05-24 13:48:23:173 - [Appium]   automationName: XCUITest
2019-05-24 13:48:23:173 - [Appium]   deviceName: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:23:173 - [Appium]   app: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa
2019-05-24 13:48:23:174 - [Appium]   udid: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:23:228 - [Appium] Deprecated server args:
2019-05-24 13:48:23:229 - [Appium]   --platform-name => --default-capabilities '{"platformName":"iOS"}'
2019-05-24 13:48:23:230 - [Appium]   --automation-name => --default-capabilities '{"automationName":"XCUITest"}'
2019-05-24 13:48:23:230 - [Appium]   --device-name => --default-capabilities '{"deviceName":"4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0"}'
2019-05-24 13:48:23:230 - [Appium]   --app => --default-capabilities '{"app":"/tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa"}'
2019-05-24 13:48:23:231 - [Appium]   -U,--udid => --default-capabilities '{"udid":"4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0"}'
2019-05-24 13:48:23:231 - [Appium] Default capabilities, which will be added to each request unless overridden by desired capabilities:
2019-05-24 13:48:23:231 - [Appium]   usePrebuiltWDA: true
2019-05-24 13:48:23:231 - [Appium]   derivedDataPath: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/DerivedData1JgqWF
2019-05-24 13:48:23:231 - [Appium]   platformName: iOS
2019-05-24 13:48:23:232 - [Appium]   automationName: XCUITest
2019-05-24 13:48:23:232 - [Appium]   deviceName: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:23:232 - [Appium]   app: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa
2019-05-24 13:48:23:232 - [Appium]   udid: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:23:429 - [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
2019-05-24 13:48:29:584 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
2019-05-24 13:48:29:584 - [HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"some_bundle_id","platformName":"iOS"},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"some_bundle_id","platformName":"iOS"},"firstMatch":[{"appium:bundleId":"some_bundle_id","platformName":"ios"}]}}
2019-05-24 13:48:29:587 - [debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"bundleId":"some_bundle_id","platformName":"iOS"},null,{"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"some_bundle_id","platformName":"iOS"},"firstMatch":[{"appium:bundleId":"some_bundle_id","platformName":"ios"}]}]
2019-05-24 13:48:29:588 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1558705709588 (06:48:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:48:29:592 - [BaseDriver] The capabilities ["usePrebuiltWDA","derivedDataPath","automationName","deviceName","app","udid"] are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.94.2) session
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium] Capabilities:
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium]   platformName: ios
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium]   usePrebuiltWDA: true
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium]   derivedDataPath: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/DerivedData1JgqWF
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   automationName: XCUITest
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   deviceName: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   app: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   udid: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   bundleId: some_bundle_id
2019-05-24 13:48:29:602 - [debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa... and MJSONWP desired capabilities {"usePrebuiltWDA":true,"der... were provided
2019-05-24 13:48:29:602 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa...
2019-05-24 13:48:29:612 - [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 2b0a8f8e-26bc-4c58-9629-66f9f7fa338d
(node:464) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
2019-05-24 13:48:29:869 - [debug] [XCUITest] Current user: 'device-farm'
2019-05-24 13:48:30:348 - [debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to '10.1' (tools v9.4.0.0.1.1526532315)
2019-05-24 13:48:42:741 - [debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '12.1'
2019-05-24 13:48:42:741 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1558705722741 (06:48:42 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:48:56:256 - [debug] [XCUITest] Available devices: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:56:257 - [debug] [XCUITest] Creating iDevice object with udid '4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0'
2019-05-24 13:48:56:260 - [XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: '4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0', real device: true
2019-05-24 13:48:56:262 - [BaseDriver] Using local app '/tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa'
2019-05-24 13:48:56:262 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Copying local zip to tmp dir
2019-05-24 13:48:56:286 - [BaseDriver] Unzipping local app '/tmp/2019424-464-d635jg.9mcjv/appium-app.zip'...
2019-05-24 13:48:56:316 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Unzipping /tmp/2019424-464-d635jg.9mcjv/appium-app.zip
2019-05-24 13:48:56:316 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Testing zip archive: /tmp/2019424-464-d635jg.9mcjv/appium-app.zip
2019-05-24 13:48:57:794 - [BaseDriver] Unzipped local app to '/tmp/2019424-464-d635jg.9mcjv/Payload/testProject.app'
2019-05-24 13:48:57:795 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1558705737795 (06:48:57 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:48:57:795 - [debug] [XCUITest] Checking whether app '/tmp/2019424-464-d635jg.9mcjv/Payload/SubmissionTracker.app' is actually present on file system
2019-05-24 13:48:57:796 - [debug] [XCUITest] App is present
2019-05-24 13:48:57:796 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'resetStarted' logged at 1558705737796 (06:48:57 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:48:57:796 - [debug] [XCUITest] Reset: running ios real device reset flow
2019-05-24 13:48:57:797 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'resetComplete' logged at 1558705737797 (06:48:57 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:48:57:799 - [debug] [iOSLog] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog
2019-05-24 13:48:57:800 - [debug] [iOSLog] Starting iOS device log capture with: 'idevicesyslog'
2019-05-24 13:48:58:584 - [debug] [XCUITest] Crash reports root '/Users/device-farm/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/9902472561' does not exist. Got nothing to gather.
2019-05-24 13:48:58:584 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'logCaptureStarted' logged at 1558705738584 (06:48:58 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:48:58:584 - [XCUITest] Setting up real device
2019-05-24 13:48:58:585 - [debug] [XCUITest] Verifying application platform
2019-05-24 13:48:58:596 - [debug] [XCUITest] CFBundleSupportedPlatforms: ["iPhoneOS"]
2019-05-24 13:49:01:091 - [debug] [XCUITest] Reset requested. Removing app with id 'some_bundle_id' from the device
2019-05-24 13:49:03:324 - [debug] [XCUITest] Installing '/tmp/2019424-464-d635jg.9mcjv/Payload/testProject.app' on device with UUID '4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0'...
2019-05-24 13:49:10:747 - [debug] [XCUITest] The app has been installed successfully.
2019-05-24 13:49:10:748 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'appInstalled' logged at 1558705750748 (06:49:10 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:49:10:750 - [XCUITest] Using WDA path: '/usr/local/avm/versions/1.9.1/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
2019-05-24 13:49:10:752 - [XCUITest] Using WDA agent: '/usr/local/avm/versions/1.9.1/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj'
2019-05-24 13:49:10:815 - [debug] [XCUITest] No obsolete cached processes from previous WDA sessions listening on port 8100 have been found
2019-05-24 13:49:10:820 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2019-05-24 13:49:10:821 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
2019-05-24 13:49:10:836 - [debug] [XCUITest] WDA is not listening at 'http://localhost:8100/'
2019-05-24 13:49:10:837 - [debug] [XCUITest] WDA is currently not running. There is nothing to cache
2019-05-24 13:49:10:837 - [debug] [XCUITest] Trying to start WebDriverAgent 1 times with 10000ms interval
2019-05-24 13:49:10:838 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1558705750838 (06:49:10 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:49:10:839 - [XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
2019-05-24 13:49:10:955 - [debug] [XCUITest] Carthage found: '/usr/local/bin/carthage'
2019-05-24 13:49:10:955 - [debug] [XCUITest] Running WebDriverAgent bootstrap script to install dependencies
2019-05-24 13:49:39:997 - [debug] [XCUITest] Creating WebDriverAgent resources directory
2019-05-24 13:49:39:998 - [debug] [XCUITest] Creating WebDriverAgent resource bundle directory
2019-05-24 13:49:39:999 - [debug] [XCUITest] Cleaning the project scheme 'WebDriverAgentLib' to make sure there are no leftovers from previous installs
2019-05-24 13:49:52:882 - [debug] [XCUITest] Cleaning the project scheme 'WebDriverAgentRunner' to make sure there are no leftovers from previous installs
2019-05-24 13:50:01:514 - [debug] [XCUITest] Killing running processes 'xcodebuild.*4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0, iproxy 8100' for the device 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0...
2019-05-24 13:50:01:602 - [debug] [XCUITest] 'pgrep -nif xcodebuild.*4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
2019-05-24 13:50:01:655 - [debug] [XCUITest] 'pgrep -nif iproxy 8100' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
2019-05-24 13:50:01:655 - [debug] [XCUITest] Starting iproxy to forward traffic from local port 8100 to device port 8100 over USB for the device 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:50:06:818 - [XCUITest] Cannot parse major and minor version numbers from platformVersion "null". Will build for the default platform instead
2019-05-24 13:50:06:819 - [debug] [XCUITest] Beginning test with command 'xcodebuild test-without-building -project /usr/local/avm/versions/1.9.1/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -derivedDataPath /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/DerivedData1JgqWF -destination id=4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0' in directory '/usr/local/avm/versions/1.9.1/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
2019-05-24 13:50:06:820 - [debug] [XCUITest] Output from xcodebuild will not be logged. To change this, use 'showXcodeLog' desired capability
2019-05-24 13:50:10:188 - [debug] [XCUITest] Waiting up to 60000ms for WebDriverAgent to start
2019-05-24 13:50:10:188 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2019-05-24 13:50:10:189 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:11:340 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2019-05-24 13:50:11:340 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:12:380 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2019-05-24 13:50:12:380 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:13:433 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2019-05-24 13:50:13:433 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:14:477 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2019-05-24 13:50:14:478 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:15:508 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2019-05-24 13:50:15:509 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:15:750 - [debug] [XCUITest] Log file for xcodebuild test: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/DerivedData1JgqWF/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2019.05.24_06-50-15--0700.xcresult/1_Test/Diagnostics/WebDriverAgentRunner-617486B3-34EB-4195-A160-0EF9A788792C/WebDriverAgentRunner-1E30900B-8D08-41D1-8C4E-7D02A3E9CDB5/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2019-05-24_065015-ghzVbu.log
2019-05-24 13:50:16:571 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'

2019-05-24 13:50:34:240 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:35:284 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2019-05-24 13:50:35:285 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:35:361 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : {\n    \"state\" : \"success\",\n    \"os\" : {\n      \"name\" : \"iOS\",\n      \"version\" : \"12.0\",\n      \"sdkVersion\" : \"12.0\"\n    },\n    \"ios\" : {\n      \"simulatorVersion\" : \"12.0\",\n      \"ip\" : \"192.168.1.10\"\n    },\n    \"build\" : {\n      \"upgradedAt\" : \"1558705779000\",\n      \"time\" : \"Nov 29 2018 13:42:57\",\n      \"productBundleIdentifier\" : \"com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"sessionId\" : \"2C9B264F-15B5-4C9B-84AE-A19F79EE11B1\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"
2019-05-24 13:50:35:363 - [debug] [XCUITest] WebDriverAgent information:
2019-05-24 13:50:35:364 - [debug] [XCUITest] {
2019-05-24 13:50:35:364 - [debug] [XCUITest]   "state": "success",
2019-05-24 13:50:35:364 - [debug] [XCUITest]   "os": {
2019-05-24 13:50:35:364 - [debug] [XCUITest]     "name": "iOS",
2019-05-24 13:50:35:364 - [debug] [XCUITest]     "version": "12.0",
2019-05-24 13:50:35:364 - [debug] [XCUITest]     "sdkVersion": "12.0"
2019-05-24 13:50:35:364 - [debug] [XCUITest]   },
2019-05-24 13:50:35:365 - [debug] [XCUITest]   "ios": {
2019-05-24 13:50:35:365 - [debug] [XCUITest]     "simulatorVersion": "12.0",
2019-05-24 13:50:35:365 - [debug] [XCUITest]     "ip": "192.168.1.10"
2019-05-24 13:50:35:365 - [debug] [XCUITest]   },
2019-05-24 13:50:35:365 - [debug] [XCUITest]   "build": {
2019-05-24 13:50:35:365 - [debug] [XCUITest]     "upgradedAt": "1558705779000",
2019-05-24 13:50:35:365 - [debug] [XCUITest]     "time": "Nov 29 2018 13:42:57",
2019-05-24 13:50:35:366 - [debug] [XCUITest]     "productBundleIdentifier": "com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner"
2019-05-24 13:50:35:366 - [debug] [XCUITest]   }
2019-05-24 13:50:35:366 - [debug] [XCUITest] }
2019-05-24 13:50:35:366 - [debug] [XCUITest] WebDriverAgent successfully started after 28545ms
2019-05-24 13:50:35:367 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1558705835367 (06:50:35 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:50:35:368 - [debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
2019-05-24 13:50:35:369 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
2019-05-24 13:50:35:370 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"some_bundle_id","arguments":[],"environment":{},"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true}}
2019-05-24 13:50:37:324 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":"My Test Project","sdkVersion":"12.0","CFBundleIdentifier":"some_bundle_id"}},"sessionId":"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E","status":0}
2019-05-24 13:50:37:324 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionStarted' logged at 1558705837324 (06:50:37 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:50:37:324 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStarted' logged at 1558705837324 (06:50:37 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:50:37:325 - [XCUITest] Skipping setting of the initial display orientation. Set the "orientation" capability to either "LANDSCAPE" or "PORTRAIT", if this is an undesired behavior.
2019-05-24 13:50:37:325 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'orientationSet' logged at 1558705837325 (06:50:37 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:50:37:326 - [Appium] New XCUITestDriver session created successfully, session 2b0a8f8e-26bc-4c58-9629-66f9f7fa338d added to master session list
2019-05-24 13:50:37:327 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1558705837327 (06:50:37 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2019-05-24 13:50:37:328 - [debug] [W3C] Cached the protocol value 'W3C' for the new session 2b0a8f8e-26bc-4c58-9629-66f9f7fa338d
2019-05-24 13:50:37:328 - [debug] [W3C] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"capabilities":{"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"platformName":"ios","usePrebuiltWDA":true,"derivedDataPath":"/tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/DerivedData1JgqWF","automationName":"XCUITest","deviceName":"4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0","app":"/tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa","udid":"4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0","bundleId":"some_bundle_id"}}
2019-05-24 13:50:37:332 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 127747 ms - 629
2019-05-24 13:50:37:332 - [HTTP] 
2019-05-24 13:50:37:517 - [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/2b0a8f8e-26bc-4c58-9629-66f9f7fa338d
2019-05-24 13:50:37:517 - [HTTP] {}
2019-05-24 13:50:37:518 - [debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.getSession() with args: ["2b0a8f8e-26bc-4c58-9629-66f9f7fa338d"]
2019-05-24 13:50:37:519 - [debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'getSession'
2019-05-24 13:50:37:530 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'getSession'
2019-05-24 13:50:37:530 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /] to [GET http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:37:615 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : {\n    \"sessionId\" : \"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E\",\n    \"capabilities\" : {\n      \"device\" : \"iphone\",\n      \"browserName\" : \"My Test Project\",\n      \"sdkVersion\" : \"12.0\",\n      \"CFBundleIdentifier\" : \"some_bundle_id\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"sessionId\" : \"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"
2019-05-24 13:50:37:635 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /wda/screen] to [GET http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E/wda/screen] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:37:869 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : {\n    \"statusBarSize\" : {\n      \"width\" : 375,\n      \"height\" : 20\n    },\n    \"scale\" : 2\n  },\n  \"sessionId\" : \"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"
2019-05-24 13:50:37:872 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/size] to [GET http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E/window/size] with no body
2019-05-24 13:50:38:006 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : {\n    \"width\" : 375,\n    \"height\" : 667\n  },\n  \"sessionId\" : \"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"
2019-05-24 13:50:38:007 - [XCUITest] Merging WDA caps over Appium caps for session detail response
2019-05-24 13:50:38:009 - [debug] [W3C] Responding to client with driver.getSession() result: {"udid":"4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0","platformName":"ios","usePrebuiltWDA":true,"derivedDataPath":"/tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/DerivedData1JgqWF","automationName":"XCUITest","deviceName":"4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0","app":"/tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa","bundleId":"some_bundle_id","device":"iphone","browserName":"My Test Project {","sdkVersion":"12.0","CFBundleIdentifier":"some_bundle_id","pixelRatio":2,"statBarHeight":20,"viewportRect":{"left":0,"top":40,"width":750,"height":1294}}
2019-05-24 13:50:38:044 - [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/2b0a8f8e-26bc-4c58-9629-66f9f7fa338d 200 493 ms - 587
2019-05-24 13:50:38:044 - [HTTP] 
2019-05-24 13:50:38:046 - [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/2b0a8f8e-26bc-4c58-9629-66f9f7fa338d
2019-05-24 13:50:38:046 - [HTTP] {}
2019-05-24 13:50:38:047 - [debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.getSession() with args: ["2b0a8f8e-26bc-4c58-9629-66f9f7fa338d"]
2019-05-24 13:50:38:047 - [debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'getSession'
2019-05-24 13:50:38:049 - [XCUITest] Merging WDA caps over Appium caps for session detail response
2019-05-24 13:50:38:050 - [debug] [W3C] Responding to client with driver.getSession() result: {"udid":"4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0","platformName":"ios","usePrebuiltWDA":true,"derivedDataPath":"/tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/DerivedData1JgqWF","automationName":"XCUITest","deviceName":"4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0","app":"/tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa","bundleId":"some_bundle_id","device":"iphone","browserName":"My Test Project","sdkVersion":"12.0","CFBundleIdentifier":"some_bundle_id","pixelRatio":2,"statBarHeight":20,"viewportRect":{"left":0,"top":40,"width":750,"height":1294}}
2019-05-24 13:50:52:923 - [HTTP] {"using":"id","value":"testInput"}
2019-05-24 13:50:52:924 - [debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","testInput","2b0a8f8e-26bc-4c58-9629-66f9f7fa338d"]
2019-05-24 13:50:52:924 - [debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'findElement'
2019-05-24 13:50:52:925 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, name, class name, -ios predicate string, -ios class chain, accessibility id
2019-05-24 13:50:52:925 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 6000000 ms for condition
2019-05-24 13:50:52:926 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
2019-05-24 13:50:52:926 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E/element] with body: {"using":"id","value":"testInput"}
2019-05-24 13:50:53:129 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"using":"id","value":"testInput","description":"unable to find an element"},"sessionId":"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E","status":7}
2019-05-24 13:50:53:130 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
2019-05-24 13:50:53:130 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waited for 205 ms so far
2019-05-24 13:50:53:709 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
2019-05-24 13:50:53:710 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E/element] with body: {"using":"id","value":"testInput"}
2019-05-24 13:50:53:923 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"using":"id","value":"testInput","description":"unable to find an element"},"sessionId":"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E","status":7}
2019-05-24 13:50:53:924 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
2019-05-24 13:50:53:924 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waited for 999 ms so far
2019-05-24 13:50:54:442 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
2019-05-24 13:50:54:442 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E/element] with body: {"using":"id","value":"testInput"}
2019-05-24 13:50:54:635 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"using":"id","value":"testInput","description":"unable to find an element"},"sessionId":"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E","status":7}
2019-05-24 13:50:54:636 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
2019-05-24 13:50:54:636 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waited for 1711 ms so far
2019-05-24 13:50:55:277 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
2019-05-24 13:50:55:277 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E/element] with body: {"using":"id","value":"testInput"}
2019-05-24 13:50:55:491 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"using":"id","value":"testInput","description":"unable to find an element"},"sessionId":"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E","status":7}
2019-05-24 13:50:55:491 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
2019-05-24 13:50:55:491 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waited for 2566 ms so far
2019-05-24 13:50:55:991 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
2019-05-24 13:50:55:992 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E/element] with body: {"using":"id","value":"testInput"}
2019-05-24 13:50:56:155 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"using":"id","value":"testInput","description":"unable to find an element"},"sessionId":"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E","status":7}
2019-05-24 13:50:56:155 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
2019-05-24 13:50:56:156 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waited for 3231 ms so far
2019-05-24 13:50:56:701 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
2019-05-24 13:50:56:702 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E/element] with body: {"using":"id","value":"testInput"}
2019-05-24 13:50:56:913 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"using":"id","value":"testInput","description":"unable to find an element"},"sessionId":"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E","status":7}
2019-05-24 13:50:56:913 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
```

Comment: Can you share the appium server logs? That will likely have the actual error.

Comment: Need some more info, what code are you running, where in the code does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting those logs! It looks like the capabilities are valid(though the bundle id is obviously not valid). The bundleId will automatically be taken from the ipa file so it shouldn't be necessary to provide that if we also have the `app` capability.

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#ios-only

> Bundle ID of the app under test. Useful for starting an app on a real device or for using other caps which require the bundle ID during test startup. To run a test on a real device using the bundle ID, you may omit the 'app' capability, but you must provide 'udid'.

The default capabilities required for the app to start should be already provided by the default appium server CLI command in the testspec.yml file.

> `appium --log-timestamp --device-name $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME --platform-name $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME --app $DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH --udid $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID --automation-name XCUITest --default-capabilities "{\"usePrebuiltWDA\": true, \"derivedDataPath\":\"$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V1\"}" >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &`

**Capabilities**

```
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.94.2) session
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium] Capabilities:
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium]   platformName: ios
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium]   usePrebuiltWDA: true
2019-05-24 13:48:29:597 - [Appium]   derivedDataPath: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/DerivedData1JgqWF
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   automationName: XCUITest
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   deviceName: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   app: /tmp/scratchmfswDs.scratch/share-djkVWj.scratch/app-A1XQ83.ipa
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   udid: 4aeaf84dd2abb30c8b5474b0fa1a9c925c9df7c0
2019-05-24 13:48:29:598 - [Appium]   bundleId: some_bundle_id
```

Since the error, in this case, is regarding how to find an element I would think the best thing to do for that is to print the [page source](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/source/) and first confirm that the element is there. You can also do this using a capability which will print the page source when the script errors.

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#general-capabilities

> printPageSourceOnFindFailure  When a find operation fails, print the current page source. Defaults to false.  e.g., true

**Appium server log snippet**

```
2019-05-24 13:50:56:701 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
2019-05-24 13:50:56:702 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E/element] with body: {"using":"id","value":"testInput"}
2019-05-24 13:50:56:913 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"using":"id","value":"testInput","description":"unable to find an element"},"sessionId":"5CDDA2BB-9B89-4359-8E8B-F8F3B99AE45E","status":7}
2019-05-24 13:50:56:913 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
```

Can you print the page source and follow up with the result?

HTH

-James

Comment: Thankyou so much. These information are very helpful for a beginner like me. But In my case, I have added more accessibility Ids on local(in react native code) and tested it on emulator where it works properly. But by mistake I was uploading old .ipa file on device farm which does not contain these new accessibility Ids. I caught this silly mistake when I tried to run my scripts on real device using appium. Thankyou so much for your support.